# Triggering excess property warnings with recursive types and mapped types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm working on a TypeScript project in which the keys of an object can either be a value, or a function which accepts a parameter whose keys are mapped from the keys of the object. I would like to trigger a warning when a function-type value attempts to destructure a property that doesn't exist on the object. Here is a simplified example of what I am describing:

```
type MappedType<T, V> = {
  [K in keyof T] : V
}

type MappingFn<T, V> = (param : MappedType<T, V>) => V;

type SelfReferentialType<T, V> = {
  [key : string] : T | MappingFn<SelfReferentialType<T, V>, V>
}

const example : SelfReferentialType<number, string> = {
  fieldA : 99,
  fieldB : ({ fieldA }) => fieldA.toUpperCase(), //works as expected
  fieldC : ({ fieldD }) => fieldD.toUpperCase() //fieldD does not exist, so I would like this to trigger a warning
}
```

To clarify, the object that the function-type properties will receive will be an object whose keys are identical to the object in which the function is declared, but whose values are of a different type. In this simplified example, they would be strings. Such an object might look something like this:

```
{
  fieldA : 'ninety-nine',
  fieldB : 'a function',
  fieldC : 'another function'
}
```

I'm not sure if the behavior I desire is even possible, but if anyone has any suggestions on how to accomplish it, or an explanation of why it's not possible, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean the value associated with a key of the object can either have a simple type like `number`, `string`, ... or the type can be an unary function?

Comment: You'd need a type that's also generic in the set of keys in your object, and possibly want a helper function to infer the keys for you.  Such as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m07ExN).  Does that meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type like `SelfReferentialType<T, U, K>` where `K` is the set of keys your object has.

```
type SelfReferentialType<T, U, K extends PropertyKey> =
    { [P in K]: T | ((o: { [P in K]: U }) => U) }
```

Presumably you'd want to manually specify `T` and `U` but have the compiler *infer* `K` based on the object literal you're using.  Unfortunately TypeScript doesn't allow for type argument inference for generic types directly, you'd need to call a helper generic *function* for that to happen.  Furthermore TypeScript doesn't allow you to specify some type arguments while it infers the rest, as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  It's either all or nothing.  The standard workaround is write a [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function.  In your case it could look like this:

```
const selfReferentialType = <T, U>() => <K extends PropertyKey>(
    srt: SelfReferentialType<T, U, K>
) => srt;
```

And use it like this:

```
const example = selfReferentialType<number, string>()({
    fieldA: 99,
    fieldB: ({ fieldA }) => fieldA.toUpperCase(), // okay
    fieldC: ({ fieldD }) => fieldD.toUpperCase() // error
})
// const example: SelfReferentialType<number, string, "fieldA" | "fieldB" | "fieldC">
```

It's a little weird to call a function with type arguments but no function arguments and then immediately call the return value as another function, but it behaves how you want: the `example` object is of type `SelfReferentialType<number, string, "fieldA" | "fieldB" | "fieldC">`, so the compiler knows that the fields don't include `"fieldD"` and you get the desired error.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&jsx=0&ts=5.1.6#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhA2AzAShREBOEB2wCWAhvACrgQA8xANFAKo0DSUEAHsDgCYDOUAChgHtIGUAwggAfFAC8AKCgKoAbygBtXlDzYoDALoAuKMSgAfKAApzAwyvWbtew7SgBfAJQyptDy9myAxgLYXMBQXAgoaJg4+ESkkDJQlDS0EuYe0lLkTKzs2Nx8gsKi4mnyilwihnBIqOhYuIQkZMl0jBKyGVKVwADcfoHBoawEALZg8NDSYRF10Y1xLdgArqMARpg0IRhaAOZpbuZK5QqIeAgcAIKGAJw3VCdQZxcAQoZHT+fwV65dnxeXAB0wAEtDAwgAwgRwukaAB6OFQAQAawIIEez2+EPeKkxHAAIr9PP9vvjgaDwZgoTCPAjmBhBBhZO5+nTBiFmCwxhMINVZlEGrFmpByCt1pswsAdthdjQAER4y5y0xQBVfDgvZVmNUXCFyjpAA)